# Ghostscript command line with postscript

Tags: ghostscript

Getting Error on following command when using inline postscript syntax. Probably syntax error but could get it what's wrong !!

**Command**

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNoCancel -dPDFFitPage -c mark "NoCancel true QueryUser 3 OutputFile (%printer%Microsoft Print to PDF) UserSettings <<DocumentName (test)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" -dNORANGEPAGESIZE -f "D:\95c46c9f-0007-415d-99b6-c9ee561821ab.pdf"
```

**Exception**

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0 (2021-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Error: /undefined in QueryUser
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   true   true
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:740/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.54.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: Just for testing purpose using Microsoft Print to PDF. In reality it should print silently on actual printer. Above command is working with c# but I want to check with gs cli.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is command line without all the baggage of trying to hide the output.

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -o "%printer%My Print to PDF" -dPrinted -dFitPage -dNORANGEPAGESIZE -f "C:\MyData\sample.pdf"
```

The print runs silent without prompt because that's how I set "My Print to PDF" rather than "MS Print to PDF" which will shout out for a filename. To silence GS see below.

That means I dont need to jump through contortions other than move/rename the output.pdf

I am showing print spooling but that would normally be just an icon on the taskbar. I could make the console minimised, To make GSwin64C silent I need to add -q and -dNoCancel, but beware you then have to watch the print icon or add a "Print Finished" statement. **NOTE:- For a batch file %% need to be doubled.**

```
GSwin64C ^
-q ^
-sDEVICE=mswinpr2 ^
-dNoCancel ^
-o "%%printer%%My Print to PDF" ^
.... other switches
```

But I dont bother as I prefer to see printer errors when they occur.

The exercise is in my view pointless its just a proof of concept since the output file is far inferior to the input.pdf. Yes I could reduce the resolution or drive the result back through GhostScript for compression.

But why since it was a perfectly good 137 KB searchable text input.pdf and was degraded to a significantly inferior 113,021 KB non text PDF. There are dozens of easier ways to get 825 times worse (or better) results using other CLI PDF handlers. However the image quality is good as we might expect from GS.
[image]

A more efficient way to convert Textual PDF to Image PDF is

```
echo Method Two "Ghostscript Convert to PDF"

"C:\Path....\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" ^
-q ^
-sDEVICE=pdfimage32 ^
-o C:\MyData\output.pdf ^
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen ^
-f "C:\MyData\input.pdf"
```

Quality should be better (I did not reduce bit depth which I could have done) thus file size is very large for mono at 3,938 KB but its 30% the size for more colours.

[image]

**[Later edit]**
You commented how to change spooler name, which in reality I see no problem with as its temporary, the moniker is either "Ghostscript Output" or "Ghostscript Document". You could call it "A Rose by any other name". However I suspect your target reason is the "Title" tag shown in the final Document. and for that you are using PDF mark on the command line which is a **very fragile** way of working.

Your construct

```
-c mark "NoCancel true QueryUser 3 OutputFile (%printer%Microsoft Print to PDF) UserSettings <<DocumentName (test)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" -dNORANGEPAGESIZE -f "D:\95c46c9f-0007-415d-99b6-c9ee561821ab.pdf"
```

My attempt in a batch file would be along the lines of

```
-c "mark /OutputFile (%%printer%%Microsoft Print to PDF) /UserSettings <</DocumentName (test)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice " -f "D:\95c46c9f-0007-415d-99b6-c9ee561821ab.pdf"
```

note I include the critical PS division=/ and need to use %% in a batch file and nothing between -c "...." and -f

So here we see "test" in the spooling
[image]

and to "test" that place this in a DragOnDrop.cmd

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNoCancel -dPDFFitPage -dNORANGEPAGESIZE ^
-c "mark /OutputFile (%%printer%%Microsoft Print to PDF) /UserSettings <</DocumentName (test)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice " ^
-f %1
```

[image]

Comment: In this case How can I change document name in printer spool ?